# Magento product slider (Ultimo)

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

I asked a similar question a few days ago but maybe it wasn't very clear, so I will try and simplify it to make it easier to follow.

I am using a Magento theme named 'Ultimo' and I have a product slider on my home page:

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured" template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider_shopbybase.phtml" category_id="45" product_count="16" breakpoints="[0, 1], [320, 2], [480, 3], [768, 4], [960, 5], [1280, 6]" pagination="1" centered="1" hide_button="1" block_name="Shop by Base"}}
```

The Ultimo developers have used the popular Owl carousel for the product sliders, which basically pulls in groups of products through their ID tag(s). The product images are assigned a URL automatically, so for example 'image1' will have the URL image1.html, so when you click on an image, it then takes you directly to that URL, which is always single product page.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true); ?>" class="product-image">
```

Ideally I would prefer to enter the URLs manually to each product in the slider, so then I can direct the users to pages containing lists of more products (I hope that makes sense).

Does anybody here have any experience of the Ultimo/Magento product sliders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a product attribute lets say '**product_slider_url**' and add your url in this from admin.

Now in your **list_featured_slider_shopbybase.phtml** easily get this newly created attribute value for each product. So,

change **$this->getProductUrl()** to **$this->getProductSliderUrl()** .

Hope this will solve your problem.